# Sound proofing a small gap

Tags: sound-dampening

I'm trying to place a small speaker (60mm x 60mm) in front of a microphone 30mm away with the space in between soundproofed and blocked. Does anyone know if rolling up a sheet of rubber (5mm-10mm thick) to form a one-layer tube/canal will give significant insulation/reduction? That is, something like: (MIC) ]=[ (SPEAKER)

where ]=[ is the canal.

Is rubber meant to be effective? I've looked up MLV, but they're much more expensive. Are there other alternatives?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are actually trying to achieve. Placing any small baffle between one & the other will block direct sound only, it will do nothing for ambient sound.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm trying to prevent the sound from the speaker from leaking into the surrounding.

Comment: If air can get from one to the other, they can hear each other. Place yourself at the microphone's position... can you hear the speaker? if you can, so can the mic. Isolation requires no continuity of 'air' & also needs mass. Right now your idea seems akin to trying to prevent the sun hitting a beach using a single umbrella.

Comment: I don't get it, are you trying to record the speaker and block out any other sound, or are you trying to stop the sound from the speaker from getting to the mic? I'm leaning towards the first, seeing as the mic is so close to the speaker(3cm).

Comment: @MarcW - you have a point, for sure. I've VTC as unclear, as either is currently a possibility.

Comment: I think hes talking about a type of tunnel technique for some sort of re amping. Either way this is a very badly put question

Comment: @Tetsujin Sure, but I'm not trying to block sound from reaching the mic. Instead, I'm trying to block sound from entering into the surrounding environment. That is, the sound from the speaker can reach the mic but is trapped inside the canal.

Comment: @MarcW Well, I'm trying to record the speaker and keep the sound from leaking out. The sound should be "sealed" inside the canal.

Comment: Your best bet is something like an isobox..

Comment: If it's an amp you're recording, then I'm assuming it will be loud. If so, I'd have to say no; there is no small,  _practical_ way to stop the sound from a loud speaker, which is essentially what you're asking. You may be able to reduce the sound a bit, muffle it so to speak, but stopping it would take a large, expensive enclosure. Can I ask why you want to isolate the sound? Maybe there is another way around it.